# ¿Como puedo verificar si existe o no registro SQL?

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo un inconveniente. Quiero verificar en este código si hay o no registros.

Con el contador como lo pongo me tira que no hay registro existiendo o no, no se que hago mal. He intentado con `if(rs.last())` y con `if(rs.next())` pero me da que no hay registros siempre.

La parte donde esta el `While` es el problema ya que quiero verificar antes del `while` si no hay registro que no entre y me enseñe un mensaje, intente con un contador como se ve en el `código` pero tampoco me muestra el mensaje cuando se debe. Es la búsqueda en una tabla, con filtro

```
    ConexionDB cc = new ConexionDB();
            //Me conecto a la BD
            Connection conect = cc.getConnection();
            //Preparo la secuencia SQL      
            PreparedStatement st = conect.prepareStatement(SSQL);
            // Ejecuto la consulta en un ResultSet
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            o.removeAllItems();
            //Tomo los datos de la BD los asigno a variables para despues agregarlos como filas 

                int contadorreg = 0;
                while (rs.next()) {

                    String c = "Alta";
                    int a = rs.getInt("altabajaproductos");
                    int id = rs.getInt("IDProducto");
                    String desc = rs.getString("Descripcio");
                    int cant = rs.getInt("Cantidad");
                    Double preS = rs.getDouble("PrecioSinIVA");
                    Double preC = rs.getDouble("PrecioConIVA");
                    int offe = rs.getInt("Oferta");
                    if (a == 0) {
                        c = "Baja";
                    }
                    contadorreg++;
                    ModeloTabla.addRow(new Object[]{id, desc, cant, preS, preC, offe, c});
                    //asignamos los datos a la tabla
                }
                if(contadorreg == 0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se encontraron registros en la BD, de esta busqueda");
                }
                contadorreg=0;
            rs.close();
            cc.desconectar();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConsultasStock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, te invito a mirar [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar esta pregunta. Hay mucho código y dices que omitamos la parte de SQL, por lo que, también te invito a mirar como realizar en [ejemplo, minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que, quien te pueda ayudar, pueda reproducir mejor el problema.

Comment: @Aritzbn Listo ahí lo mejore. Gracias por los enlaces !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con esta sencilla instrucción deberías poder comprobar si el `resultset` esta vació:

```
if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
    System.out.println("No data"); 
}
```

<sub>[Pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867194/java-resultset-how-to-check-if-there-are-any-results) similar en el sitio en ingles, me he basado en ello</sub>

Para comprender mejor que es lo que hace la función puedes mirarlo en su [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst()). `isBeforeFirst` devuelve `true` si el [cursor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html) esta antes de la primera fila. Y `false` si el cursor esta en cualquier otra fila o no tiene filas.

> true if the cursor is before the first row; false if the cursor is at any other position or the result set contains no rows

Comment: Me explicarías  un poco que hace para poder entender . Se que isBeforeFirst() regresa el puntero al primero. Pero como funciona en si la verificación. Solo para entender su funcionamiento mas a fondo !

Comment: Me funciono gracias . Me explicarías un poco de porque no me funcionaba ? O el código que mandaste !

Comment: @BlackCliver He añadido información sobre el método en la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte un tiempo de responder a mi duda, puede que este resuelta en el foro, pero lo esta en el de ingles y mi ingles es medio chueco, usted me lo soluciono en español. Gracias y saludos !